# Most frequent element in matrix

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I need to find most frequent element in matrix, and print it. If there are more than one most frequent elements, program should print the smallest of them.

How could my code of finding maximum element of 1D array be implemented in matrix (2D array)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int i, j, k = 0, m = 3, n = 4, vel = 8, count = 0, maxCount = 0;
  double mat[3][4], maxElement, arr[100] = { 1.3, 4.2, 1.3, 5, 4.2, 6.8, 3.7 };

  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      scanf("%lf", &mat[i][j]);
  for (i = 0; i < vel; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < vel; j++) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
        count++;
        if (count > maxCount)
          maxElement = arr[j];
      }
    }
  }
  printf("Most frequent is: %g", maxElement);
}
```

Comment: I don’t think your 1D algorithm is working. arra[7] is read but not initialised. MaxCount is never modified.

Comment: Try to write the problem in other words : find the different number in array , for each number count the number of time it appears…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm does not work for the 1D matrix, but once fixed, it can be used for the 2D matrix unchanged:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double find_most_frequent(const double *arr, size_t vel) {
    size_t i, j, maxcount = 0, mostfreq = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < vel; i++) {
        size_t count = 1;
        for (j = i + 1; j < vel; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                count++;
        }
        if (maxcount < count || (maxcount == count && arr[mostfreq] > arr[i])) {
            maxcount = count;
            mostfreq = i;
        }
    }
    return arr[mostfreq];
} 

#define ROWS  3
#define COLS  4

int main() {
    double mat[ROWS][COLS];
    double arr[] = { 1.3, 4.2, 1.3, 5, 4.2, 6.8, 3.7 };

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            if (scanf("%lf", &mat[i][j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Most frequent in array is: %g\n", find_most_frequent(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
    printf("Most frequent in matrix is: %g\n", find_most_frequent(&mat[0][0], sizeof(mat) / sizeof(mat[0][0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If matrix is `{{4,5},{5,7}}` it would print 4 as most frequent element, could you fix that?

Comment: @codproe: I fixed a bug in the code: it would have printed the largest instead of the smallest in case multiple numbers are most frequent in the set.  For `double mat[2][2] = {{4,5},{5,7}};` it would print `5` as expected.